# $.post array of data

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to post some array of data to controller..
My view is like:

```
<script>
   $.post("/",{
       person: [
           { id: 1, name: "a" },
           { id: 2, name: "b" }
       ]
   });
</script>
```

and in my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(List<Person> person)
{
    //something
}
```

When I inspect the sent http data, I see that data is:

```
person[0][id]
person[0][name]
person[1][id]
person[1][name]
```

but the correct for default model binder is:

```
person[0].id
person[0].name
person[1].id
person[1].name
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: try JSON.stringify({person:[....]}) in $.post()

Comment: @prashanth Doing this person is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do it with `$.post` you need use `$.ajax` because you need to set the `contentType` to `'application/json'` to make the mobel binder happy what you cannot do with `$.post`

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify({
            person: [
                { id: 1, name: "a" },
                { id: 2, name: "b" }
            ]
        }),
        contentType: 'application/json'
    });
```

And you also need to `JSON.stringify` your data to make it work with the modelbinder.